# Stop Consumer when is disconnected (Spring Boot + Kafka)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, consumer

i need help with a consumer in spring boot. I need stop the application when is disconnect for example 10 min. when is disconnected

```
2021-08-16 18:39:21.927  WARN 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest-] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:39:24.942  WARN 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:39:24.943  INFO 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler              : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1591961485, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
```

or when can't connect

```
2021-08-16 18:42:15.960  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:42:15.961  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-08-16 18:42:19.125  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:42:19.126  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I used ConsumerFactory and ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory for all configuration of my consumer

Answer (score 0):

Kafka client will retry automatically to recover from the disconnection, you should see more logs for that, also you can change the log level to `debug` to see more details.

Also see this this ticket for more updates in the future on this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6520 .